# ConversationalRetrievalChain using with FewShotChatMessagePromptTemplate

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

```
def get_conversation_chain(vectorstore):
    llm = HuggingFaceEndpoint(repo_id="mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1", temperature=1.0, model_kwargs={"max_length": 2048})
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key='chat_history', return_messages=True)

    examples = [
        {"question": "There is no flow, what should I do? ", "output": "To resolve a No Flow alarm on your RD96 system, follow these steps:\
                Check Tank Levels: Ensure the chemical and water tanks are sufficiently filled.\
                During Chemical Dosing: If empty, refill the tank, cancel the dosing process, and wash the line to remove trapped air.\
                During Washing: Ensure the water supply meets the system's needs.\
                Viscosity and Material Checks: Confirm that the chemical viscosity is within the specified limits and that materials are available for dosing.\
                Pump and Flowmeter Checks: Ensure the pump is operational and check the flowmeter for accurate flow detection."},
        {"question": "Piston isn't moving, how to fix it?", "output": "To fix a piston that is not moving in the RD96 system, you should:\
                Remove Physical Obstructions: Check for and remove any objects blocking the piston's movement.\
                Inspect the Valve: Verify the valve associated with the piston's operation is functioning correctly.\
                Check Air Connections: Ensure the air supply connections to the piston are secure and providing adequate pressure."},
    ]

    example_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("human", "{question}"),
            ("ai", "{output}"),
        ]
    )
    few_shot_prompt = FewShotChatMessagePromptTemplate(
        example_prompt=example_prompt,
        examples=examples,
    )

    final_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", "RD96 Technical Service Assistant is designed to assist with a wide range of technical tasks.\
      It can answer technical questions, guide users through troubleshooting processes, provide updates on technology news, and offer support for various technical services.\
        The assistant is knowledgeable in fields such as IT, electronics, software, and hardware. It aims to provide accurate, up-to-date information and practical solutions.\
    When it encounters queries beyond its expertise or available information, it will use its browsing capability to find and summarize relevant, current information from trusted sources.\
        The assistant is programmed to ensure user-friendly interactions and aims to deliver responses that are not only informative but also easy to understand for users of all technical backgrounds.\
        Firstly, use the PDF I provided to you"),
            few_shot_prompt,
            ("human", "{question}"),
        ]

    )

    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=final_prompt, input_variables=['question', 'output'])
    
    conversation_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
        memory=memory,
        combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": prompt}
    )
    return conversation_chain
```

I'm experiencing an issue with my Python application that involves the `langchain_core` library. When attempting to create a conversation chain using `PromptTemplate` with `langchain_core`, I receive a `KeyError: 'template'`. This error occurs during the initialization of a `PromptTemplate` object, where it seems the `template` key is either missing or not correctly recognized in the provided parameters. The application is intended to work with language models and handle conversational inputs, but this error is preventing it from running correctly. I've checked the documentation and my code multiple times but can't seem to figure out why this `KeyError` is being raised. Could someone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

I attempted to resolve this by casting the `final_prompt` to a string with `str(final_prompt)`, but the issue persists.

My error:

[image: my error]